# How to change Default Mainwindows form in wpf to WIndow1 c#.I am using Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#

how to change startup form in WPF Application ...i am using Visual Studio 2012 and xaml code look like this..there is no StartupUri to change the default form ..how can i do this

```
< Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="700" Width="525"  WindowState="Maximized">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are modifying `Window1.xaml`, you need to edit `App.xaml`, that is where you tell it which window to open initially.